# grep to find literal [square brackets] with specific data

Tags: regex, unix, awk, grep, pcregrep

My file contains the following lines:

```
hello_400 [200]
world_678 [201]
this [301]
is [302]
your [200]
friendly_103 [404]
utility [200]
grep [200]
```

I'm only looking for lines that ends with `[200]`. I did try escaping the square brackets with the following patterns:

- `cat file | grep \[200\]`
- `cat file | grep \\[200\\]$`

and the results either contain all of the lines or nothing. It's very confusing.

Comment: Your last command `cat file | grep \\[200\\]$` shloud work with `sh`, `bash` and `dash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use quotes around strings in shell unless you NEED to remove the quotes for some reason (e.g. filename expansion), see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, so by default do `grep 'foo'` instead of `grep foo`. Then you just have to escape the `[` regexp metacharacter in your string to make it literal, i.e. `grep '\[200]' file`.

Instead of using grep and having to escape regexp metachars to make them behave as literal though, just use awk which supports literal string comparisons on specific fields:

```
$ awk '$NF=="[200]"' file
hello_400 [200]
your [200]
utility [200]
grep [200]
```

or across the whole line:

```
$ awk 'index($0,"[200]")' file
hello_400 [200]
your [200]
utility [200]
grep [200]
```

Comment: Genius! Thanks Ed.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to escape `[` and `]` and quote complete regex with single quotes to prevent your shell from interpreting the regex.

```
grep '\[200\]$' file
```

Output:

```
hello_400 [200]
your [200]
utility [200]
grep [200]
```